# Does anyone know how to send an email with Novell GroupWise from a C# .NET application?

Tags: c#, email, shell, novell, groupwise

I am trying to find a way to shell or communicate with GroupWise so that I can open and then send an email to a recipient programatically with C#.  I don't have any code, just looking for an api call or a way to shell to get the email open.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16923344/214919

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's got a COM automation layer, find it back in your Project + Add Reference, COM tab list.  API documentation [is here](http://support.novell.com/techcenter/articles/ana20000813.html).

Definitely consider using System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient instead.